# How should I solve this differential equation involving hyperbolic functions?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Show that the solution of $$2\sinh(x)\frac{\Bbb d^2y}{\Bbb dx^2}-2\cosh(x)\frac{\Bbb dy}{\Bbb dx}+y\sinh^3(x)=0,\ y(1)=0,\ y(2)=2$$ is $$y=\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}(\cosh(x)-\cosh(1))\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\cosh(2)-\cosh(1))\right)}.$$

Here’s my work:

Let $t=\sinh(x)$ and $\frac{\Bbb dt}{\Bbb dx}=\cosh(x)$.

Then
\begin{align}
\frac{\Bbb d^2y}{\Bbb dx^2} &= \frac{\Bbb d}{\Bbb dx} \left(\frac{\Bbb dt}{\Bbb dx}\right) \\ &= \frac{\Bbb d}{\Bbb dx}(\cosh(x)) \\ &= \frac{\Bbb dt}{\Bbb dx} \\ &= \cosh(x),
\end{align} so
\begin{align}
\frac{\Bbb dy}{\Bbb dx} &= \frac{\Bbb dy}{\Bbb dt} \cdot \frac{\Bbb dt}{\Bbb dx} \\ &= \frac{\Bbb dy}{\Bbb dt} \cdot \cosh(x) \\ &= t\frac{\Bbb dy}{\Bbb dt}.
\end{align}

Now we have $$2t^2 \frac{\Bbb d^2y}{\Bbb dt^2} -2t\cosh(x) \frac{\Bbb dy}{\Bbb dt} +y\sinh^3(x)=0 \\ \implies t^2 \frac{\Bbb d^2y}{\Bbb dt^2} -t\cosh(x) \frac{\Bbb dy}{\Bbb dt} +\frac{y}{2}\sinh^3(x)=0.$$

But how to proceed from here? Am I solving this problem using the correct approach? What to do from here?

Comment: You are overthinking. You are not supposed to solve the ODE, just to show that the proposed solution does indeed satisfy the ODE and the boundary conditions.

Comment: Yes, but I was told not to use direct substitution in order to verify that this is a solution. It says no marks will be given by doing so. Thus, I must solve this ODE and show/prove that the given solution is the final answer.

Comment: FWIW, you can go on replacing $x$ to end up with$$2t(t^2+1)\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - 2\frac{dy}{dt} + t^3y = 0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is interesting to notice that, if you let
$$y(x)=z(t)\qquad \text{with} \qquad t=a \cosh (x)$$ the equation becomes
$$2a^2\,z''(t)+z(t)=0\quad \implies \quad z(t)=c_1 \cos \left(\frac{t}{a\sqrt{2} }\right)+c_2 \sin
   \left(\frac{t}{a\sqrt{2}}\right)$$ Doing the same with $ t=a \sinh (x)$  or $t=a e^x$does not lead to any simplification.

**Edit**

If
$$y(x)=z\big(t(x)\big)$$
$$y'(x)=t'(x)\,z'\big(t(x)\big)$$
$$y''(x)=t''(x) \,z'\big(t(x)\big)+t'(x)^2 \,z''\big(t(x)\big)$$

Comment: This looks very simple, but I want to know how did you get the equation $2a^2 z''(t)+z(t)=0$?

Comment: @Purity. Chain rule for sure.

Comment: I still don't understand. I know that the chain rule must be applied but I cannot observe where to apply this.

Comment: Now I got it. $2a^2\cdot \sinh^3(x)\cdot z''(t)+2a\cdot \sinh(x)\cdot \cosh(x)\cdot z'(t)-2a\cdot \sinh(x)\cdot \cosh(x)\cdot z'(t)+\sinh^3(x)\cdot z(t)=0\implies 2a^2\cdot z''(t)+z(t)=0$. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Now I got the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your first big formula is wrong. After computing $\frac{dt}{dx}=\cosh(x)$, the next step should be
$$
\frac{d^2t}{dx^2}=\sinh(x).
$$

---

But at first glance the structure of the equation is
$$
2\Bigl[p(x)y''(x)-p'(x)y'(x)\Bigr]+p(x)^3y(x)=0
$$
with $p(x)=\sinh(x)$, suggesting the application of the quotient rule. Or perhaps trying differently using $p'(x)=\sinh(x)$, $p(x)=\cosh(x)=p''(x)$, the structure now is
$$
2\Bigl[p'(x)y''(x)-p''(x)y'(x)\Bigr]+p'(x)^3y(x)=0,
$$
which contains elements associated with the second order chain rule.
So try for $y(x)=f(p(x))$ to get $y'(x)=f'(x)p'(x)$ and $$y''(x)=f''(x)p'(x)^2+f'(x)p''(x).$$ Now inserting this reduces the equation quite well to
$$
2p'(x)\Bigl[p'(x)^2f''(p(x))+p''(x)f'(p(x))\Bigr]-2p''(x)\Bigl[p'(x)f'(p(x))\Bigr]+p'(x)^3f(p(x))=0
$$
The middle terms cancel, and $p'(x)\ne 0$ on the domain of the ODE, so one is left with, using $t=p(x)$,
$$
2f''(t)+f(t)=0
$$
With $y(1)=0$ this has $f(p(1))=0$ and thus the solution
$$
f(t)=C\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2}}(t-p(1))\right)
$$
and the constant is determined by the second boundary condition.